# Base class variable is not accessible

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have two classes in Actionscript 3. I am using FlashBuilder 4.6. The SDK is 3.6A. The two classes are in a separate library. This library is referenced in the Active project.

My first (base) class is:

```
public class BaseDTO
    {
        public var errorCode:int;
        public var errorMessage:String;

        public function BaseDTO()
        {
        }
    }
```

The second (derived) class is:

```
public class Configurations extends BaseDTO
    {

    }
```

In my active project (non-library), I am calling Configurations like this:

```
var c:Configurations = new Configurations();
c.errorCode = 0;
```

there are two references in two separate classes. Now the problems is that in first class which is basically a creationComplete handler of the application, I am getting a compile time error:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property errorCode through a
>   reference with static type dto.configs:Configurations.

And the other class which is calling the same code is throwing a runtime exception:

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property errorCode on
>   dto.configs.Configurations.

I am not sure if I have explained it enough. Let me know if there are any other questions. I have been banging my head now for couple of hours now.

I have tried to create a new project, tried to use the same code to reference the configuration, and it works. Extremely strange.

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you add to you code examples imports part? Looks like you have "Automatically declare stage instances" trouble

Comment: It would appear no publicly visible property exists on dto.configs.Configurations.  If `Configurations` really is as empty as outlined above, you may want to either declare the property, or set your class to Dynamic.  See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html

Comment: where can I set "Automatically declare stage instances"? I am using Flash Builder. It looks like this option is only available in Flex.

Comment: Since the two classes are in separate libraries, I think it would be useful to elaborate on how those are linked (merged, RSL, external), firstly among each other, and secondly into the main project.

Comment: Damn, I know what the problem is. BaseDTO is declared in both, project and the library and in the same namespace! Flex compiler didn't complain about it. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Class was declared twice, in library and the project. Also, the namespace was same. Flex compiler should have raised warning on it though.